# MVC and databinding to subselection of model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, razor

I want to bind a view to a collection of my custom model. This should not be any problem, if I go for the generel way to do this, looping through the model items from my view, and using the bracket syntax when stating the model:

Ie:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Id)
```

My issue is that I need to do some grouping of my model items, and thus I've made a sub-selection of my items:

```
@foreach(var itemType in Model.GroupBy(item => item.Type).Select(grp => grp.First()))
{
    <p>@itemType:</p>

    var selection = Model
        .Where(p => p.Type == itemType)
        .OrderBy(p => p.CreationDate);

    for (int i = 0; i < selection.Count(); i++) {
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => selection[i].Id)
       @* all my other element bindings here... *@
       ...
    }
```

Now, the problem is that my controller method, receiving the submitted form, gets an empty model. So the serialization of the model is broken at some point; maybe MVC doesn't like my "selection" variable name?.. Or what could my problem be, and how could I solve it?

Comment: What does the view model look like that you're trying to bind to (in the controller method that's receiving the submission)? Is it just a collection and you're only trying return a subset of the original collection?

Comment: My view model is just a collection of a simple POCO class. And my view can then edit the items in the collection. So, I don't want to reduce the original collection. The subset 'selection' is only to iterate over the subset items of each of the groups in my collection.

Comment: I'm more interested in the naming of the items, but I might have enough to go on here

Comment: don't do your grouping in the view. do it in your action method

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the names that get generated for each item when your view is generated.The model binder uses the name-value pairs to figure out how to map your form values onto the view model you're expecting in your controller.

When you were using `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m[i].Id)`, that was fine and would generate the following name attribute in your HTML:

```
name="[0].ModelId"
```

a later one would be

```
name="[5].ModelId"
```

and so forth.

Here's what HTML is being generated with your view:

[image: HTML source of view]

There's two problems here:

1. The value "selection" appears at the front of the name
2. It's using zero twice as the array index

This is happening because of the way all of the HTML tags with the for at the end work (HiddenFor, TextboxFor, etc.). They determine the name attribute based on the lambda expression - since you were using `m => m[0].ModelId` in the first one, it used `[0].ModelId` as the name. In the second, you use `m=> selection[0].ModelId`, so it used `selection[i].ModelId` (it removes whatever variable you used as part of your lambda.

So, how do you fix this?

You can approach this in one of two ways given the current setup. you can use a counter outside of the loop and use that as the array index, or you can take advantage of using an extra hidden field as an index field. For either approach, you're going to have to drop the strongly typed HiddenFor/TextBoxFor and use Hidden/TextBox instead so you can manually set the name of the HTML element that's being generated.

What happens with the index field is you have your item names as something like the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Index" value="Model1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="[Model1].ModelId" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="[Model1].ModelValue" value="Some value"/>
```

On the first input tag, I called it index and set some value that would act as the index for this related set of values. On the remaining ones, I used the value set as the value in the first one as the array index and then just the name of the property. This approach ends up being especially useful if you're in a situation where you're adding/removing items from your list and can't guarantee that you'll have all of the numbers in sequence when posting back.

So this is what your Razor code could look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < selection.Count(); i++) {
    @Html.Hidden("Index", "Model"+selection[i].ModelId)
    @Html.Hidden("[Model"+selection[i].ModelId + "].ModelId", selection[i].ModelId)
    @Html.Hidden("[Model"+selection[i].ModelId + "].CreateDate", selection[i].CreateDate)
    @Html.Hidden("[Model"+selection[i].ModelId + "].ModelValue", selection[i].ModelValue)
```

As a sidenote, I chose to include the word "Model" as part of the index so that way it definitely knows that it's referring to it as a dictionary-like entry instead of the number location in an array. I don't know if you absolutely need to do it that way, I haven't actually tried the other way. I used ModelId as the index value because that should hopefully be a unique value.

The end result is you should have generated HTML looking like this (in terms of the name attributes):

[image]

Hopefully that helps!